# Dominant 3 frequencies in the DFT and Energy of the 3 dominant frequencies from a list

Tags: python, numpy, fft, dft

```
data = [222, 251,212,188 , 244, 202, 198, 244, 175, 216]

import numpy as np
print("Discrete fourier transform")
print(np.fft.fft(data))
print("Inverse discrete fourier transform")
print(np.fft.ifft(data))
```

Above code is the `dft` code using `numpy`.

**The Question is:** 
 How to find **Dominant 3 frequencies in the DFT** and **Energy of the 3 dominant frequencies** such like `1-D` `list`?

Additionally:

> Is there anyway `DFT` and `IDFT` from `2-D` or `3-D` list and corresponding **Dominant 3 frequencies in the DFT** and **Energy of the 3 dominant frequencies**?

Comment: What's the question? Is it 1d, 2d, or 3d?

Comment: @SargeATM. Sir please show the edited question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easy to make mistakes when dealing with discrete transforms because there are many variations of implementations that can have a direct effect on the mathematics of the results. Since your data consists of all real number, numbers with no imaginary component, the np.fft.rfft functions are easier to use. I have included some sample python/bash code to show it's use and how to find the energy spectrum for the data you have included.

## Calculating the Energy

```
import numpy as np
data = [222, 251,212,188 , 244, 202, 198, 244, 175, 216]

#print("One-sided discrete fourier transform coefficients")
complex_one_sided_spectrum = np.fft.rfft(data, norm='ortho')
#print(complex_one_sided_spectrum)
#print("Magnitude")
one_sided_spectrum_magnitude = np.abs(complex_one_sided_spectrum)
#print(one_sided_spectrum_magnitude)
#print("Wave Numbers")
wave_numbers = np.arange(len(complex_one_sided_spectrum))
#print(wave_numbers)
#print("Energy Spectrum")
wave_energy = one_sided_spectrum_magnitude * one_sided_spectrum_magnitude
#print(wave_energy)

#output table to command line
print("\t".join(['wave numbers', 'energy spectrum', 'dft magnitude', 'dft coefficient']))
for i in range(0,len(complex_one_sided_spectrum)):
    row = [str(wave_numbers[i]), 
            str(wave_energy[i]),
            str(one_sided_spectrum_magnitude[i]), 
            str(complex_one_sided_spectrum[i])]
    print("\t".join(row))
```

#### Output

```
wave number  energy spectrum     dft magnitude       dft coefficient
0            463110.4000000001   680.5221524682353   (680.5221524682353+0j)
1            156.53675171891524  12.511464811080884  (8.323007319698682-9.341536323065784j)
2            374.41182935941566  19.349724270888608  (13.380080448562616-13.978028349857077j)
3            1014.9632482810841  31.85848785302096   (15.39407513156416-27.892395005177345j)
4            1240.8881706405841  35.22624264153905   (-18.43972470483202+30.01440859738189j)
5            250.0               15.811388300841896  (-15.811388300841896+0j)
```

## Finding the Dominant 3 Wave Numbers/Frequencies

I'm going to use bash here (because I just want to), but it is easily translatable into python code.

```
$ python 52675886.py | sort --key=2 --reverse | column -t -s $'\t' | head -n 4
wave number  energy spectrum     dft magnitude       dft coefficient
0            463110.4000000001   680.5221524682353   (680.5221524682353+0j)
2            374.41182935941566  19.349724270888608  (13.380080448562616-13.978028349857077j)
5            250.0               15.811388300841896  (-15.811388300841896+0j)
```

So the dominant three waves are 0. 2, and 5. To convert wave numbers into frequencies, you would need to know the sampling rate of the data.

**UPDATE**

## Finding the Dominant 3 Waves in Python

```
# convert attribute arrays into a list of wave dictionaries
waves = []
for i in wave_numbers:
    wave = {'wave_number': wave_numbers[i],
            'wave_energy': wave_energy[i],
            'one_sided_spectrum_magnitude': one_sided_spectrum_magnitude[i],
            'complex_one_sided_spectrum': complex_one_sided_spectrum[i]}
    waves.append(wave)
#print(waves)

# tell sorted that we want to compare the wave_energy
def wave_energy_comparison_key(wave):
    return wave['wave_energy']

sorted_waves = sorted(waves, key=wave_energy_comparison_key, reverse=True)
#print(sorted_waves)

top_3_waves = [sorted_waves[i] for i in range(0,3)]
print(top_3_waves)
```

Comment: How can  convert this bash `python 52675886.py | sort --key=2 --reverse | column -t -s $'\t' | head -n 4` into python code, Sir ?

Comment: Great Sir. You are a legend, Sir. <3